# background not fixed and scaled on iPhone (but working on every other device)

Tags: custom-background

I have designed a website using Twenty Twenty-One and I'm quite satisfied with it. The website is https://www.coldsilence.de.

Here, I specifically wanted to achieve two backgrounds, one for mobile and one for desktop. In addition, the backgrounds should be fixed, so they don't scroll, and scale to the actual size of the screen.

This works very well on all desktop devices (including MacBooks) and on all Android devices. However, iPhones are causing issues. On iPhones, the background is extremely zoomed in and also scrolls along. It looks terrible.

I'm using the following JavaScript code before the closing  tag in the footer.php to achieve what I want (and what works well on almost all devices):

```
<script>
  function updateBackgroundImage() {
    var desktopImage = 'http://coldsilence.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/UpscaledDesktop-scaled.jpeg';
    var mobileImage = 'http://coldsilence.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/UpscaledMobile-scaled.jpeg';
    var breakpoint = 1000;
    
    if (window.innerWidth >= breakpoint) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + desktopImage + ')';
      document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = 'fixed';
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + mobileImage + ')';
      document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = 'fixed';
    }

    document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 'center center';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
  }

  function updateLogoAlignment() {
    var breakpoint = 1000;

    var logo = document.querySelector(".site-logo .custom-logo-link img");
    if (!logo) return;

    if (window.innerWidth <= breakpoint) {
      logo.style.marginLeft = "auto";
      logo.style.marginRight = "auto";
      logo.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      logo.style.marginLeft = "0";
      logo.style.marginRight = "auto";
      logo.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', updateBackgroundImage);
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateLogoAlignment);
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateBackgroundImage);
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateLogoAlignment);
</script>
```

Please note, there is also code included here that ensures our logo is left-aligned on desktop devices and centered on mobile devices.

I have also tried to do a lot with CSS, but that failed on most other devices. The JavaScript solution in the footer is the furthest I've come so far.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do here to fix the issue on iPhones?

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with WordPress.

Comment: Well, I created the website with wordpress, I actively edited the footer.php of the wordpress theme, I dont do anything here outside of wordpress, so this is basically the exact opposite of "doesn't have anything to do with WP".

Comment: The behaviour of a background image in HTML and CSS is entirely unrelated to WordPress. In what way is WordPress relevant to getting an answer to your question? None of the code in your question is WordPress code.